# c++ MFC CBitmap , CImage or BITMAP structure , get resolution (DPI)

Tags: c++, bitmap, dpi

HEllo , i can not find any way to get horizontal or/and vertical resolution for bitmap.
If you know how to get it, please say it me , Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question that you want to know the size of the image?

```
CBitmap -> GetBitmapDimension
CImage -> GetWidth and GetHeight
BITMAP -> bmWidth and bmHeight
```

Or that you want to know the size it will have on a display?

```
GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using the GdiPlus library, specifically the `Image` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

use GDI+  Bitmap or Image class.

Comment: You might have supplied a bit of code, even if the question was a bit sketchy.